# Is the list of rooting methods supposed to contain bloatware?

Tags: discussion, questions

I had a rather unpleasant experience with rooting my phone using KingoRoot as described [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device). I ended up installing some [bloatware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171453/did-kingoroot-install-bloatware-on-my-phone-or-is-this-a-legitimate-android-loc) which now I can't remove. I would like to know what I should have expected:

1. Anything at all, as I do everywhere else on the Internet.
2. Bloatware is considered OK on Android.SE, as long as it doesn't steal my data or doesn't ask for ransom.
3. I was unlucky, everyone else have rooted their phones with KingoRoot and didn't get any bloatware.
4. I was the first one who tried and noticed the bloatware.
5. Something else.

I was going to edit the answer to either remove KingoRoot from it, or add a warning message next to it, but I figured that in cases other than #4 my edit would do harm instead of good, so I decided to ask first.

Comment: I'd think something around #4 as well (definitely not #1 or #2) – but I don't have any experiences with Kingo I could go by and argue. Only thing I've noticed is that if people come here having issues with their rooted device, Kingo is mentioned more often than I'd expect considering there are so many other rooting tools around. So thanks for bringing this up! I definitely look forward to answers on this one.

Comment: I'm with @Izzy, #4 seems like the most likely cause for your situation. I don't think it calls for outright removal of Kingo from the list, but if Kingo is confirmed to install bloatware - even if the user can opt-out - it would be best for us to make that very clear on the community wiki which you've referenced.

Comment: @dotVezz Thanks, both of you. I will be rooting another device soon which I wouldn't mind reflashing in the worst case. I'll take care to check what exactly gets installed, and if I get the same bloatware as before without a possibility to opt-out, I'll add a warning to community wiki.

Comment: @dotVezz I agree with you, and suggest turning your comment into an answer.

Comment: To be frank, I'd rather King, Kingo, iRoot and similar one-clickers are simply banned from the site, they don't really support many new devices despite what they advertised, and are always a source of infinite (often low-quality, duplicate) questions: unable to root, unable to replace with SuperSU, bloatwares, backdoors, etc. Sadly a lot of (slightly older) devices still have to rely on them...

Comment: Related to the threats of using such methods - see [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/131690/131553)

Comment: I agree with @AndyYan about the banning of one-click-root apps that are known to be controversial in regards to malwares and such. In my opinion, even if they *may* allow to root older devices, this is no excuse for us to suggest potentially harmful software to users who are newbies on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, for some phones, bloatware will inevitably be installed on the phone **if third-party tools are used**.

Usually, rooting would involve this:

```
Flash a custom recovery -> use said recovery to flash a zip -> profit
```

Of course, a custom recovery won't introduce bloatware in 99.999% of cases. The zip file, provided you use [one that is from a very reliable author](https://plus.google.com/+Chainfire/posts/27xToSqi5em), is also bloat-free.

Now, some phones go through this process:

```
Install a tool, usually in an APK form -> Press a button -> profit
```

This is where things can go many ways. Your phone's fate depends solely on the authors of the tool.

Some tools, such as [towelroot](https://towelroot.com/), probably do not care about profits and as such simply does their job (rooting the phone) and nothing else. Unfortunately, other tools (like KingRoot/KingoRoot) do care about profits.

To answer your question, unless you know how to deal with low-level stuff instead of using third-party tools, **bloatware is inevitable**.

---

Since you already acquired root, you can probably:

1. Install SuperSU/Superuser from the Play Store
2. Install a root-enabled app manager
3. Disable internet connection
4. Remove KingRoot/KingoRoot/whatever-Rooting-App-You-Used and **everything** they installed.
5. Restart phone, and deny all unfamiliar `su` requests.

   - Since some bloatware have monitoring services that monitor their bloat and reinstall if necessary (ala persistent Android malware)
   - Also remove said unfamiliar apps using #2. Rinse and repeat.
   - This does not guarantee a clean system. There may be other unwanted stuff lingering about.
   - Some SU apps (e.g. Superuser) have this option to allow all `su` requests during boot. **Disable this while you're sanitizing your phone**. Do not enable unless you know you need to.

Comment: I couldn't help noticing that my phone's fate depends on authors of the tool in both cases.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev But the difference here is, again, the authors of the tools. The authors on the first scenario are trusted by the community and have a record of *not* including bloatware.

Comment: I would say each tool should be judged on its own merits and not by the rooting method used. But if you're confident about that, then someone should go though the community wiki and either remove all APK-based methods from it or write a big fat **contains bloatware** warning next to them.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Exactly.

Comment: Towelroot is safe... if you trust me and my reverse engineering art, which you can find [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/165582/152843).

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Law #1: If a bad guy can persuade you to run his program on your computer, it's not solely your computer anymore. Law #2: If a bad guy can alter the operating system on your computer, it's not your computer anymore. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh278941.aspx